# Make Generic Class Codable

Tags: swift, generics, init, codable

I have this class:

```swift
class Course<T: Dish> {
    var amount: Int
    var type: T
    init(amount: Int, type: T) {
        self.amount = amount
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

I don’t have access to `Dish`. But let’s assume this implementation:

```swift
class Dish {
    var calories: Double
    init(calories: Double) {
        self.calories = calories
    }
}

class Pudding: Dish {
    static var iceCream = Dish(calories: 400)
    static var chocoloteMousse = Dish(calories: 600)
}
```

I now want to encode/decode it to JSON like so:

```swift
import Foundation
var course = Course(amount: 1, type: Pudding.iceCream)
var encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(course)
var decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Course.self, from: encoded)
```

So I add `Codable` conformity:

```swift
class Course<T: Dish>: Codable
```

As the functions for `Codable` can’t be synthesized I get these error messages:

```
Type 'Course' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
Type 'Course' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
```

So, I need to write init and encode() myself.

Somewhere in the initializer I would decode the generic type `T`.

**How do I specify the type `T` in the initializer to make it generic when there is no reference to that type in the function signature?**

```
required init<T: Dish>(from decoder: Decoder) throws
```

The above results in this error message `Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are wantng use a generic here; it doesn;t seem to make sense unless there's a wider context.  Just make the Course's type property be of type Dish?

Comment: You say you don't have access to Dish but do you what properties the class has?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes

Comment: Mousse is not really pudding. Ice cream is definitely not pudding.

Comment: @flanker Can’t make Course's type property of type Dish. I want to access `Pudding` specific properties, in case `type` is a `Pudding` (not only a `Dish`).

Comment: @Jessy When in UK territory both very much is ;)

Comment: That’s gross. We need to buy them some refrigerators.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said above, you haven't made a case for this having to be generic yet. But if you can make that case, and you can't just extend Dish to be Codable, just put a restriction on the local dish. And rename it, because "T" and "type" are imprecise.

```swift
class Course<Dish: ModuleName.Dish & Codable>: Codable {
  var amount: Int
  var dish: Dish
```

The best thing you can do to make this easier on yourself is to forbid subclassing. Forever, in all of your own types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by “local dish”?

Comment: You naming was inaccurate. Your `type / T` was actually a specialized `Dish`. By using the horrible convention `T` (the convention is the industry's from a long time ago, not your convention. I'm not faulting you for it.), that didn't make itself evident enough. What it actually is, is a `Course.Dish`, which is a refinement of the `Dish` in your module. Prefix the module-scoped `Dish` with the module name (the `ModuleName.Dish` above) for disambiguation. Then `Dish`, when used within `Course`, will be the _locally-scoped_ one—a "local dish".