# Make initializer generic without type in function signature

Tags: swift, generics, types, signature, inference

I have broken down a more complex matter to this class. This way it doesn’t make sense, but it is easier to talk about:

```swift
class GenericClass<Type: Any> {
    var object: Type?

    enum DataType {
        case string, integer
    }

    init(dataType: DataType) {
        switch dataType {
        case .string:
            object = "string" // Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Type'
        case .integer:
            object = 1 // Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Type'
        default:
            object = nil
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I make this initializer infer the type `Type` when there is no reference in the function signature?**

I asked a related question before (probably with to much cluttered detail): [Make Generic Class Codable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749399/make-generic-class-codable)

Comment: You're misunderstanding what a generic type is. Generic means, any type possibly satisfying some constraint known at compile-time. You're trying to use it as `Any`. Perhaps, what you need is an [enum with associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148)? What are you trying to achieve with this type? How is it going to be used?

Comment: `AnyObject` should be used for classes only. If you want `String` and `Integer` (structures) you need `Any` or simply a generic type without any constraint.

Comment: agree with @NewDev (as per comment on your related post)  For this abstract scenario using an enum with associated value would work far better (and be far simpler), although it would depend to a degree on how you plan to use it in the wider picture.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I will look into the enum/associated value solution. Also, I corrected `AnyObject` to `Any`.

Comment: @fulty12 No need to use `Any`. Just don't add any constraint. A generic type can represent any object type as well as `Any`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this answers your question but this is how you are supposed to create an initializer for a generic structure/class without a specific type in the function signature (generic initializer):

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    let object: T
    init(_ object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }
}
```

---

```
let stringClass = GenericClass("string")
print(stringClass.object)
let intClass = GenericClass(1)
print(intClass.object)
```

---

This will print

> string
> 1

Comment: This is the “normal” way to go. My special case doesn’t determine the `Type` through the function signature (`init(_ object: T)`). In my case the generic type is determined via the `dataType` object at runtime. I would like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The actual goal/benefit of generics is to get rid of type checks at runtime.

Referring and in addition to Leo's answer if you want to constrain the types to `String` and `Int` do it at compile time

```
protocol GenericClassCompatible {}

extension String : GenericClassCompatible {}
extension Int : GenericClassCompatible {}

class GenericClass<T : GenericClassCompatible> {
    let object: T
    init(_ object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }
}
```

If the type in the `init` method is not `String` or `Int` you'll get an error at **compile time**.